# Rust custom adapter and generics

Tags: generics, iterator, rust, adapter

I am a beginner with Rust and I want to implement an adapter which takes an iterator of `u8` or `&u8` as input and outputs some chunks.

I don't know how to make my program compile. I made the adapter work without using `ends_with_separator()` where there is no constraint on the type of iterator, but now I need to define my adaptor so that it accepts only iterators of `u8` or `&u8` and I don't know how to do that.

```
pub struct Chunk<T> {
    pub data: Vec<T>,
}

pub struct Chunker<I> {
    pub iter: I,
}

impl<I> Chunker<I> {
    fn ends_with_separator(buf: &Vec<u8>) -> bool {
        match buf.last() {
            Some(v) => v % 7 == 0,
            None => true,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for Chunker<I> {
    type Item = Chunk<I::Item>;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        while let Some(v) = self.iter.next() {
            buf.push(v);
            if Self::ends_with_separator(&buf) {
                return Some(Chunk { data: buf });
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let chunker = Chunker { iter: (0u8..10) };
    for chunk in chunker {
        println!("{:?}", chunk.data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, my problem was purely syntaxic:

`impl<I: Iterator<Item=u8>> Iterator for Chunker<I>`

Comment: Next time you have a “I don't know how to make my program compile.” problem: 1) reduce your code to the smallest example that exhibit the same error, 2) *give the error*.

Comment: This is the small version of the program already. My problem was more like "how to do something" using the correct syntax.

I didn't show an error message because it didn't really make sense here.